# How to pull key-value pairs from a txt file using gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Lets say I have a bunch of key-value pairs in a txt file and I want to use gradle to pull them into variables I can use. How would I go about doing that?

What Im trying to do is not hardcode my storepass and other related signing info in my build.gradle files and keep them out of hosted source control.

What I want to do is something like

```
propertiesFile file(/buildProperties.txt)

storeFile file(propertiesFile.getProperty("myStoreFile"))
storePassword propertiesFile.getProperty("myStorePassword")
keyAlias propertiesFile.getProperty("myKeyAlias")
keyPassword propertiesFile.getProperty("myKeyPassword")
```

I know this is something simple and can be done but an hour of googling has produced no solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle provides a mechanism for this [out of the box](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties). Simply place these properties in *USER_HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties* and they will be implicitly available in your build script.

Comment: I've decided to stick with the way Im using but this would've worked had I known about it.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured it out.

```
def Properties props = new Properties()
def propFile = new File('path\to\file.txt')

 release {

        if (propFile.canRead()) {
            props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

            storeFile file(props['key.store'])
            storePassword props['key.store.password']
            keyAlias props['key.alias']
            keyPassword props['key.alias.password']
        }

    }
```